# CakePHP 3.3 autoloading plugin controllers error "Cannot declare class"

Tags: php, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

Even though the classes for plugins are correctly configured in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "Blog\\": "./plugins/Blog/src",
        "Media\\": "./plugins/Media/src",
        "Cms\\": "./plugins/Cms/src",
        "Feedback\\": "./plugins/Feedback/src"
    }
},
```

and plugins are loaded in bootstrap.php:

```
Plugin::load('Blog', ['routes' => true, 'autoload' => true]);
Plugin::load('Cms', ['routes' => true, 'autoload' => true]);
Plugin::load('Media', ['routes' => true, 'autoload' => true]);
Plugin::load('Feedback', ['routes' => true, 'autoload' => true]);
```

I get errors on several plugin controllers:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Blog\Controller\AuthorsController, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/xxx/plugins/Blog/src/Controller/AuthorsController.php on line 0
```

If I remove the line:

```
"Blog\\": "./plugins/Blog/src",
```

from composer.json, I get cakererror:

```
Error: Blog.AuthorsController could not be found.
Error: Create the class AuthorsController below in file: /var/www/html/xxx/plugins/Blog/src/Controller/AuthorsController.php
```

and if I remove the autoload option for Blog plugin in bootstrap.php, I get the same error as for removing line from composer.json.

What could be the problem for cakePHP not autoloading / double loading controllers?

Checked file permissions, its 644 for the AuthorsController and 755 for the Controller directory.

Declaration for AuthorsController is as follows:

```
namespace Blog\Controller;
use Blog\Controller\AppController;

class AuthorsController extends AppController {
}
```

Comment: do you have followed usage of namespace properly?

Comment: "The name is already in use" would seem to indicate that it's trying to define the class twice. Any chance that you have a duplicate definition of it, or you're `require`-ing the file manually, or some such thing?

Comment: Nope, loading classes automatically - no loadModel() or require on the road. Just trying to perform a simple view action for an ID

Comment: Important: this happens for all my projects while updating from 3.2.14 to 3.3.0